# How do I access parsing of .nimble files from the nimble package?

Tags: parsing, nim-lang, nimble-nim

Nim as a language provides `.nimble` files to describe its packages ([example of a `.nimble` file](https://github.com/PhilippMDoerner/nimword/blob/main/nimword.nimble)). I know that the file is parsed by the [`nimble` package and CLI-tool](https://github.com/nim-lang/nimble), as they need the information inside the `.nimble` file for their tasks.

I want basically all the information in there, dependencies, author, license, description, version, all of it. So in order to not do the same work twice and potentially run into issues should the format change, I would like to use the `nimble` package itself to parse the `.nimble` file for me.

I know the correct proc for it, which is [`getPkgInfoFromFile`](https://github.com/nim-lang/nimble/blob/c701d6e7905dfe084e58efffc8493bfb22842295/src/nimblepkg/packageparser.nim#L432), but I can't seem to access it with `import nimble/nimblepkg/packageparser`.
Whenever I use that line I receive an error that there is no such file.

What am I doing wrong?

Further: `getPkgInfoFromFile` requires an `Options` instance that it generates when parsing a CLI command. I don't have a CLI command, so I'm not generating such an instance, can I use the proc somehow without one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to ringabout I came to the correct solution, but first to the question.

#### Question 1: How do I access the proc in the first place?

You can access nimble like a package, but the import is not `import nimble/nimblepkg/packageparser` it is directly `import nimblepkg/packageparser`.

This requires you to have both `nimble' installed as a library as well as the` compiler` installed as a library.

So you'll have to install those first:

```bash
  nimble install nimble
  nimble install nim # Originally this was called "compiler", but was renamed to "nim"
```

Ignore any warnings if they pop up.

Now you can compile the following dummy-example:

```
#dummy.nim
import nimblepkg/packageparser

echo "Pointer to packageparser proc: ", packageparser.getPkgInfoFromFile.repr
```

with: `nimble -d:ssl --mm:refc -r build` (-d:ssl is required for nimble's HTTP-client and --mm:refc is required as nimble appears to not work with orc)

#### Question 2: Can I run the `getPkgInfoFromFile` without an `Options` instance?

Yes-ish. You still need one, but it doesn't have to be a "real" one, you can just instantiate one yourself on the fly.

```
import nimblepkg/[options, packageinfotypes, packageparser]

proc generateDummyOptions(): Options =
  result = initOptions()
  result.setNimBin()
  result.setNimbleDir()

proc parseNimbleFile*(nimblePath: string): PackageInfo =
  let options = generateDummyOptions()

  result = getPkgInfoFromFile(nimblePath.NimbleFile, options)
```